# Embed FireFox / Chrome Browser in Windows Phone 8

Tags: html, browser, windows-phone-8, embed

Is it possible to embed a FireFox / Chrome browser into Windows Phone 8? Is it possible using GeckoFX web browser control, or are there other ways? If so, how can it be done?

If the browser can be embedded, then can we use the features of HTML5 which are supported by FireFox / Chrome browsers within the embedded browser inside Windows Phone 8?

Comment: What's the problem in using existing `WebBrowser` control?

Comment: Does the WebBrowser control support all latest HTML5 features like WebAudio API?

Comment: Do you mean `<audio />` ?

Comment: Yes:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio


Supported browsers
    Mobile
        Android Browser 2.3
        Blackberry Browser
        Google Chrome for Android
        Internet Explorer Mobile 9
        Mobile Safari 4[2]
        Mozilla Firefox for Android
        Opera Mobile 11
        Tizen


There is no mention of IE10/11, which is used in Windows Phone 8

Answer (score 0):

`<audio />` is fully supported in Windows Phone `WebBrowser` control. I've tested with this code. Simply create HTML5 app from Visual Studio template and edit HTML with the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you suggested. However, [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) implies `<audio />` were already supported in IE9. So I think you shouldn't have any problems using them in IE10 and 11.

Answer (score 0):

There is an application for [Firefox on Windows Phone 8](http://wp8appstore.com/apps/productivity-tools/firefox/) exists. You can download it and run on your wp8 phone.